# oauth2 and jwt in different domains

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

is this a good practice? (service 1 and 2 are in different domains)

[image]

1. I let the user authenticate with oauth2 providers like google or github
2. the user (authenticated) want to use a service; he contact the api gateway
3. the api gateway create and sign a JWT with his private key
4. the api gateway forward the user request with the JWT
5. one of the service verify the JWT using the public key (take it from the secrets manager) and perform the original user request

Answer (score 0):

For different domains/resource servers, one could also use the **"aud"** claim in **JWT** for verifying the intended recipient of the token as a part of additional validation. If your auth server is adding *aud* claim while issuing the token then the resource server can verifying the same by extracting the *aud* claim and matching against the domain name.

> "aud" (Audience) Claim
>
> The "aud" (audience) claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is
> intended for. Each principal intended to process the JWT MUST identify
> itself with a value in the audience claim. If the principal processing
> the claim does not identify itself with a value in the "aud" claim
> when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be rejected. In the
> general case, the "aud" value is an array of case- sensitive strings,
> each containing a StringOrURI value. In the special case when the JWT
> has one audience, the "aud" value MAY be a single case-sensitive
> string containing a StringOrURI value. The interpretation of audience
> values is generally application specific.

Comment: are you referring to step 5?

Comment: No, that anyway resource server to validate the incoming token. Just after that the resource server should look for `aud` in the claims extracted from the token.

Comment: I have a similar use case, could you tell how you solved it and what problems you have encountered? In your scheme... How did you validate authorization (not authentication)? Does the API Gateway take care of it or is each service responsible for limiting its resources? If each service is in charge, how have you done it? In case service 1,2 and others require data from all users (for example, to list all), you have duplicated the content in all services or you have communicated directly with rest or graphql, in that case, you have used oauth2 for server to server credentials or how?